# How to convert MONActivityView Method for Swift

Tags: swift, custom-controls, uiactivityindicatorview, addsubview

I'm trying to use a custom ActivityIndicatorView that's written in Obj-C.  It contains a method needed to Center the indicator in the UIView frame.  I'm having trouble using it in my Swift code. Here is the code...

```
- (void)placeAtTheCenterWithView:(UIView *)view {
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                         multiplier:1.0f
                                                           constant:0.0f]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                             toItem:self.view
                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                         multiplier:1.0f
                                                           constant:0.0f]];
}
```

The link to the GitHub is https://github.com/mownier/MONActivityIndicatorView

How can I use this in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you looking for ? Convert objective-c to swift ? If that so, here is the translation :

```
func placeAtTheCenterWithView(view: UIView) {
    let xCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let yCenterConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    self.view.addConstraints([xCenterConstraint, yCenterConstraint])
}
```

Cheers ;)